# Binding a dropdownlist in mvc3 to a dictionary?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

What am I missing here?

ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IDictionary<int, string> Entities { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public override ActionResult Create(string id)
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();

        IEnumerable<Entity> theEntities = (IEnumerable < Entity >)db.GetEntities();
        model.Entities= theEntities.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x.Name);

        return View(model);            
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EntityId,
    new SelectList(Model.Entities, "Id", "Name"))</div>
</div>
```

Error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair....does not
>   contain a property with the name 'Id'

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`KeyValuePair` has properties `Key` and `Value`.  You are better off declaring `Entities` as type `IEnumerable<Entity>`, then your view would work as-is:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
}
```

OR, if you really need to use a Dictionary<>, change your view:

```
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EntityId, new SelectList(Model.Entities, "Key", "Value"))
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thx for reply but my id's are not contig.  Results back from list to which I wish to build select list and store selected id is like: [2]="Joes ent", [9]="Johns ent"...etc,...so that's why I wish to capture the selected id that corresponds to the associated id in the dstabase model.

Comment: Then change your view to `<div class="editor-field">@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.EntityId,
    new SelectList(Model.Entities, "Key", "Value"))</div>
</div>`