# Binding Dictionary list to dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor

I have list of dictionary I neeed to bind to dropdownlist in mvc.

```
public static readonly Dictionary<string, string> lstGender = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "M", "Male" }, { "F", "Female" } };
```

How can I bind the lstGender to dropdownlist in mvc.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding a dropdownlist in mvc3 to a dictionary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983895/binding-a-dropdownlist-in-mvc3-to-a-dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

do like this..

```
 Dictionary<Int32, string> dict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            dict.Add(0, "All");
            dict.Add(1, "Male");
            dict.Add(2, "Female");
            dict.Add(3, "Snr Citizen");
            dict.Add(4, "Children");


            ViewBag.Buckets = dict.Select(item => new SelectListItem() { Value = item.Key.ToString(), Text = item.Value });
```

in view bind like this

*@Html.DropDownList("ddlbucket", (IEnumerable)ViewBag.Buckets)*